# Graphviz egde addition conundrum

Tags: graphviz, dot, neato

I am trying to make images with Graphviz that will illustrate some process that involves adding a few edges to an existing graph. It is crucial that the vertices and edges of the base graph remain in place.

I've tried to add my new edges with [constraint=false] but keep getting different layouts for the base and the new graph, wherever I add more than one edge. Another method I tried with little to show for it was running dot for the graph with all the extra edges and then manually removing the extra lines - still no dice.

The graph I am trying to draw is this:

```
graph G{
overlap=scale;
node [weight=.2,height=.1];
edge [len=2.1];
3--2 [constraint=false];
4--1 [constraint=false];
5--3 [constraint=false];
6--1 ;
6--2 ;
6--3 ;
6--4 ;
6--5 ;
7--1 ;
7--2 ;
7--3 ;
7--4 ;
7--5 ;
8--1 ;
8--2 ;
8--3 ;
8--4 ;
8--5 ;
} 

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
```

Comment: Can you try running dot over it, and using the dot output option?  That should include the layout information for everything in the file, which might permit you to then tweak the layout to your liking when you add extra edges.

Comment: @Gian: I tried that, but it doesn't work. The layout just changes randomly, no matter what I do.

Comment: You would need to enable 'no layout mode' for the run of `dot` which includes layout information in the file.

Comment: @Gian: Or maybe not, I can't tell actually, since the results are completely oversized and I can't see most of them in Ghostview.

Comment: @Gian: How do I do that?

Comment: `dot --help` will give you all the options you need.  I suspect it's going to be something like `dot -n -s1 file.dot`, where `-n` is "no layout", and `-s1` says "apply scale factor 1`.

Comment: @Gian: alas, it doesn't work. I try: >> dot.exe -Kfdp -n -s1 c:\neatofiles\tempdot.dot > c:\neatofiles\newl.dot

Comment: And when I use the new layout even as it is, without touching it, it gets blown away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try with :

```
3--2 [style="invis"];
4--1 [style="invis"];
5--3 [style="invis"];
```

and then :

```
3--2 [style="bold"];
4--1 [style="bold"];
5--3 [style="bold"];
```

to show - and emphasis - the new edges.

The nodes and edges that are `invis` are not shown but still used to compute the layout.

Comment: This sounds just like what I wanted! Thanks a million. I'll try it out.

Comment: Sure, I just hadn't time to test it; will try to get to it today.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Graphviz, there are many GUI graph analysis tools that let you run layout algorithms and position things manually. You can fix node positions, and even color or change the width the added edges to make them stand out. These tasks are trivial in [NodeXL](https://nodexl.codeplex.com/) (C#), a great  open source tool that integrates network analysis into Excel 2007/2010 (*Disclaimer: I'm an advisor for it*).

Here is your graph visualized in [NodeXL](https://nodexl.codeplex.com/), and another image with the new edges colored red.
[image: Initial graph.]
[image: Graph with added edges colored in red.]

To create the second image, just open up the 'Edges' worksheet in NodeXL and paste in your data in the first three columns like this:

```
3   2   red
4   1   red
5   3   red
6   1
6   2
6   3
6   4
6   5
7   1
7   2
7   3
7   4
7   5
8   1
8   2
8   3
8   4
8   5
```

You can download the [graphml](http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/) file [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/999969/perm/so_felix_goldberg.graphml), which includes your data and the node coordinates that you could import into NodeXL.

There are tons of other open source GUI tools to visualize graphs, like [Gephi](https://gephi.org/) (Java) and [Cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/) (Java), while [Pajek](http://vlado.fmf.uni-lj.si/pub/networks/pajek/), [UCINet](https://sites.google.com/site/ucinetsoftware/home), [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html) and [Tom Sawyer](http://www.tomsawyer.com/products/layout/index.php) are some proprietary alternatives.